# CI: Controllers in subfolder - removing subfolder from url

Tags: codeigniter

I want to group my controllers, views and models into `public/` and `members/` subfolders.

But for the public stuff, I don't want /public/ to show in the URL, so:

http://mysite.com/ & http://mysite.com/section/

should point to: /public/home & public/section/

How should I change routes.php to accommodate this?

(I'm fine with members/ stuff having members/ in the url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make http://mysite.com/ point to `/public/home` you will need to mark `public/home` as your default controller. You will also need to add a specific route to make http://mysite.com/section point to `/public/section`. Try this (the regex is a little dubious in my opinion, but may do what you want):

```
$route['default_controller'] = "public/home";
$route['section/(.*?)'] = "public/section/$1";
```

Comment: Thx. Though, I was wondering Instead of adding a route for every public section, if I could say `anything requested where first subfolder isn't members/, remove the first subfolder` ?

Comment: For that I believe you'll need *mod_rewrite*: **routes.php** I believe is currently restricted to single controllers at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly see if this works for you:

```
$route['section'] = "public/section";
```

Your index page would remain as "public/index.php"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add routes for every controller.

This works for me:

```
$route['members'] = 'members'; // route members to members
$route['members/(.*?)'] = 'members/$1'; // route members/... to members/...
$route['(.*?)'] = 'public/$1'; // route anything but above lines to public/...
```

The first two lines are intentionally redundant to protect 'members' segment from being routed to 'public'. And the third line does the magic.